# Resume code execution after ScheduledExecutorService is done

Tags: java, executorservice

I am trying to use `ScheduledExecutorService` in an interval of 5 seconds with initial delay of 5 seconds till a condition is satisfied. Below is my code block

```
 if (true) {
   ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           try {
               //API calls which gives boolean true/false                              
               if (true) {
                   executorService.shutdown();
               }
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               System.out.println("Excepton in shutting down executorService: " + ex);
           }
       }
   };
   executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   System.out.println("Executor ended");
}

 //Other lines of code which should get executed after ScheduledExecutorService is done executing
 //Call to API etc.
```

I want my other lines and api call code to execute after `ScheduledExecutorService` is done executing (Basically stop further program execution apart from ScheduledExecutorService)  but at the moment it's not happening. At present while `ScheduledExecutorService` is waiting to be executed my down api call code executes. Also, i am not able to use any variable declared globally to be used inside `ScheduledExecutorService`. How to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: You want the current thread to block until your newly created thread is done? Why not just use the thread you have, loop and check the API every 5s using Thread.sleep()? What am I missing?